# Save on disk h264 packages received using PyAV

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pickle, h.264, avconv

I'm using PyAV to read packets from H.264 stream during 5 minutes. I need to save the packets encoded on disk and load and decode them later. I tried to use pickle to save the packets, but it cannot serialize them. What can I do? Here is part of my code (an exception is thrown when I try to save the packets using pickle, so the code doesn't work):

```
import av
import time
import pickle

# open container
container = av.open(url) # url from a h264 stream
# read packages from stream during 5 minutes and add them to a list
packets = []
initialTime = time.time()
for packet in container.demux(video = 0):
    packets.append(packet) 
    if time.time() - initialTime > 300:
        break
# save packets
pickle.dump(packets, open("packets.obj", "wb"))
# load packets, get the frames they contain and saves them as files
load_packets = pickle.load(open("packets.obj", "rb"))
for idx, packet in enumerate(load_packets):
    frame = packet.decode_one()
    if frame is not None:
        frame.to_image().save('frame-%04d-%04d.jpg' % (frame.index, idx))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of saving the packets using pickle, I created an output mp4 container and muxed to it the packets read from the H.264 stream. When I need to load them later, I just process the video generated by the container.